# Determine when surface dial rotation end

Tags: c#, wpf

I need some really accurate way to determine when surface dial rotation end:

```
private void OnRotationChanged(RadialController sender, RadialControllerRotationChangedEventArgs args)
{
    double angle = args.RotationDeltaInDegrees;
}
```

I stay really lost about how can determine in ultra accurate way when rotation end.

This is my first try but work super erratic.

```
bool start = true;
private void OnRotationChanged(RadialController sender, RadialControllerRotationChangedEventArgs args)
{
    if (start == true)
    {
    start = false;
   //send mouse left down event relative to mouse position
    VirtualMouse.LeftDown(0, 0);
    }

    if (timer != null)
    {
        timer.Tick -= timer_Tick;
    }
    timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromMillisecond(10) };
    timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
    timer.Start();


   if (args.RotationDeltaInDegrees > 0)
   {
//move mouse 1 pixel + Y relative to mouse postion
    VirtualMouse.Move(0, 1);
   }

   else
   {
 //move mouse 1 pixel  - Y relative to mouse postion
    VirtualMouse.LeftDown(0, -1);
   }


}


void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
start = true;
//release the left mouse down relative to mouse position
VirtualMouse.LeftUp(0, 0);
}
```

When I said accurate, I mean some  way to detect in any scenario.
Example, if you rotate slow and timer is around 1ms, every new event from dial (rotated slow) never reach the unhook in time.  If I increase the timer all the whole detection result in a non accurate process adding non desired latency.
I know this not is the way to go, just testing, but not idea how can achieve a proper detection in scenarios when I rotate the dial slow, or faster for obtain a real indicator the dial stop of rotate or is rotating.

Determine when rotation start is a cake, but rotarion end?

Surface dial can provide precision of 0.1 degres, is really accurate optical device. So one complete rotation is capable of provide 3600 events/angles report.

......dont know,  thinking and thinking.

Comment: You could start at giving a bit more precise requirements. Requirements as ultra accurate are useless, what is it you want to do, where are you stuck and what are eventual latency times that you don't want to exceed when rotation is ending. What are you doing with the rotations?

Comment: You are right, I edit the original question and show a example of my first an only bad working try.
As you can see when I said accurate, need be really accurate. 
I understand there is a point need be defined where some slow rotation need be discarded and considered as dial is not rotating.
Well I want achieve the minimum  possible value in accurate way.
Apologize my non perfect English, not is my native language.

Comment: This is another aspect of Heisenberg's uncertainty principle, you can't mess with the Laws of the Universe.  Describe why it is so important to detect the end of motion and why ButtonClick/Press as a positive feedback is not suitable and somebody might have a better idea.

Comment: I'm not sure how you want to know it ended other than it's no longer reporting.  Using a timer though, IMO, is probably the worse idea.  Can you describe the goal in your question because I'm almost certain there's a more elegant solution that you're possibly over looking.

Comment: I also don't know who voted to close this question but I believe it's a reasonable question to ask.  I don't believe it was worded the best but it's legit.

Comment: Now the example is super clear......….I hope! :)
Michael thanks for not close this. Is super simplified code, but show exactly the problem. Mouse events sent to third party software.

Comment: Ups, I forgot mention code is updated, take a look guys.

Comment: This is another aspect of Heisenberg's uncertainty principle, you can't mess with the Laws of the Universe...……….I start think there is no way to achieve what I try to do.